# Can't take off the paragraph tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code is written to scrape news content from bbc. So far, it works but displays the paragraph tags in it. I have tried using regular expressions to remove the html tags but still doesn't work. I need assistance with this please.

Thanks

```
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar 
import time
import os

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders= [('User-agent','Mozilla')]

bbcRSSFeed = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml')

numberstories=[len(bbcRSSFeed)]
FeedLinks=[]
FeedTitles=[]

for post in bbcRSSFeed.entries:
    FeedLinks.append(post.link)
    FeedTitles.append(post.title)

limit=2
counter=0
paraStringList = []

for i in FeedLinks:
    #if counter<FeedLinks: #displays the content of every link
    if counter<limit:
        print "["+i +"]"
        newpage = urlopen(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(newpage)
        text = soup.select('.story-body p') #content of the news story
        print (text)
        counter+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted just the text from the selected elements, then use [`element.get_text()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
text = '\n\n'.join([para.get_text(' ', strip=True) for para in soup.select('.story-body p')])
```

Comment: From rss feeds, i was able to scrape the content from each feed but now attempting to save each output into individual txt files with their titles as file names tiles e.g newstitle1.txt, newstitle2.txt...but so far, using the code below, it gives me the index.txt eg 0.txt, 1.txt.... any ideas on how to fix this?           

           with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as handle:
                    handle.write('text')

Comment: Follow-up questions like that don't really fit in comments; better ask a new question for those.

Comment: just bothered that i might have to put down the entire code again just for this question. If you have an idea on what i can do, that will be so helpful. Thanks

Comment: @hepzibah: You can produce a simple example that reproduces your problem, instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57287/discussion-between-hepzibah-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 1):

```
  text = "\n".join([s.text for s in soup.select('.story-body p')])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in text.contents:
    print( x )
```

it give all from `<p>` - with internal tags.

BeautifulSoup 3.2.1